# Python multiprocessing shared memory without copy

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

I'm currently working on a project for fun, involving calculating way too many numbers of the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). Thing is, I want it to go fast and I also don't want to loose too much progress if I have to do an update or have a computer issues....

So I over-engineered that, and I am currently looking to implement it with multiprocessing, but everywhere I look the only way to share memory in that case is to make a duplicate of it and that takes about an hour for (Yeah I have very big numbers)

Is there any way to share a dictionary with multiprocessing without making a copy of it?

Here is the code, currently with my last implementation using threading *instead* of using *multiprocessing*. (ignore the bad timekeeping of this, i'll fix it later)

```
import threading
import time


def printProgressBar(iteration, total, prefix="", suffix="", decimals=1, length=100, fill="█", printEnd="\r"):
    """
    Call in a loop to create terminal progress bar
    @params:
        iteration   - Required  : current iteration (Int)
        total       - Required  : total iterations (Int)
        prefix      - Optional  : prefix string (Str)
        suffix      - Optional  : suffix string (Str)
        decimals    - Optional  : positive number of decimals in percent complete (Int)
        length      - Optional  : character length of bar (Int)
        fill        - Optional  : bar fill character (Str)
        printEnd    - Optional  : end character (e.g. "\r", "\r\n") (Str)
    """
    percent = ("{0:." + str(decimals) + "f}").format(100 * (iteration / float(total)))
    filledLength = int(length * iteration // total)
    bar = fill * filledLength + "-" * (length - filledLength)
    print(
        f"\r{prefix} |{bar}| {percent}% {suffix} {time.strftime('%dd %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(time.time() - start_time - 86400)).replace('31d', '0d')}",
        end=printEnd,
    )
    # Print New Line on Complete
    if iteration == total:
        print()


dict47 = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1}
dict47[0] = 2


def fibSequence(n):
    if n not in dict47:
        dict47[n] = fibSequence(n - 1) + fibSequence(n - 2)
        if n > dict47[0]:
            dict47[0] = n
        if n > 5 and not ((n - 3) % (iterations // 100) == 0) and not ((n - 2) % (iterations // 100) == 0):
            dict47.pop(n - 3, None)

    return dict47[n]


def makeBackup(start, num, total):
    x = threading.Thread(target=writeBackup, args=(num,), daemon=False)
    y = threading.Thread(target=writeBackup, args=(num - 1,), daemon=False)
    x.start()
    y.start()

    x.join()
    y.join()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(
        f'{num/10000000}% done after {time.strftime("%dd %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(time.time() - start - 86400)).replace("31d", "0d")}'
    )
    timings = open("times.txt", "a")
    timings.write(str(int(time.time() - start)) + "\n")
    timings.close()




def writeBackup(num):
    file = open(f".temp/fib{num}.txt", "a")
    file.write(str(num) + " : " + str(dict47[num]))
    file.close()
    dict47.pop(num, None)


def loadDict():
    from pathlib import Path

    maximum = 0
    for n in range(1, 100):
        if Path(f".temp/fib{n*10000000}.txt").is_file():
            maximum = n * 10000000
    print("Maximum number found:", maximum)

    if maximum != 0:
        file = open(f".temp/fib{maximum}.txt", "r")
        temp = "".join(file.readlines())
        dict47[maximum] = int(temp.lstrip(str(maximum) + " : "))
        file.close()

        file = open(f".temp/fib{maximum - 1}.txt", "r")
        temp = "".join(file.readlines())
        dict47[maximum - 1] = int(temp.lstrip(str(maximum - 1) + " : "))
        file.close()

        dict47[0] = maximum
        print("Dictionary loaded at ", maximum)
    else:
        print("No dictionary found, starting from scratch")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        timings = open("times.txt", "r")
        lastTime = int(timings.readlines()[-1])
        start_time = time.time() - lastTime
        timings.close()
    except:
        start_time = time.time() + 86400
    print("Start duration:", time.strftime("%dd %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(time.time() - start_time)).replace("31d", "0d"))
    try:
        iterations = int(input("Enter the number of iterations: "))
    except:
        iterations = 1000000000
    print(iterations, "iterations will be performed")
    loadDict()
    num = dict47[0]
    while num < iterations:
        if num == 2:
            num += 248
        else:
            num += 250
        fibSequence(num)
        if num % 1000 == 0:
            printProgressBar(num, iterations, prefix="Progress:", suffix="Complete", length=100)
        if num % (iterations // 100) == 0:
            save = threading.Thread(
                target=makeBackup,
                args=(start_time, num, iterations),
                daemon=False,
            )
            save.start()

    file = open("fib.txt", "a")
    file.write(str(iterations) + " : " + str(fibSequence(iterations)) + "\n")
    file.close()
    try:
        save.join()
    except:
        print("No save thread running, exiting...")
```

Comment: Is the issue here writing to a shared file? The multiprocessing module should pickle any shared resources and manage access to them, so there shouldn't be copies of any shared resources.

Comment: Basically I store everything in a dictionary, and then I want to write numbers to their individual files, because I already know the time it takes. I'm already trying to limit the points where it could slow down, so that dictionary (dict47) is the last point where I have to take data from the calculating part to the save part.

Comment: The multiprocessing module has a Pipe class that might be useful here, although I haven't used it myself so I couldn't say for sure. I'm thinking you could pipe the output of each process to a specific file.

Comment: From what I understand, pipes have the same issue, (if I understood correctly) it is a shared memory spot that you can read from or write to, in a similar way to lists with but removing an item after reading it. 
Also I think I got confused with the differences between pipes, sharedmemory and manager things (manager has the issue of copying). The real issue with sharedmemory is that it is only supporting values or arrays, but not dictionarries. I'll keep looking.

Comment: That surprises me a bit because my understanding was multiprocessing objects needed to be pickable, which dicts are, but tbh I'm not totally familiar with the specifics of SharedMemory objects. Wish I could help you more here.

Comment: Thanks for trying ^^
I think that by using a pool I might be able to do that, but I'm pretty sure it also makes a copy

Comment: Soo after some testing, it looks like since the dict is a global var it is also accessible into other processes? I'm not sure of how it works but it does
Simply replacing the `threading.Thread` by `multiprocessing.Process` seemed to work.
Ended up making 1 to 1 000 000 about 80% faster, but it is CPU limited at that point, hopefully it will have a greater impact on the larger numbers who are limited by something else. It might also be a good idea to implement it on the loading part, maybe it will also increase loading times

Comment: Sweet, glad to hear! As long as it works, we don't ask questions....